# Downgrade Conversion from Swagger 2.0 to 1.2

Tags: converters, swagger, swagger-2.0

There are some tools (e.g. mashape) that only support older versions of swagger. Are there any utilities for downgrading Swagger Version 2.0 JSON specs into the older 1.2 version?

I would be OK with a tool that does the downgrade as a best-effort and drops features that are not supported in the older version.

Answer (score 2):

You can use restlet studio to convert between swagger 1.2, swagger 2.0 and RAML.

You can try it here : http://studio.restlet.com

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I just tried this; the import worked OK, but the export didn't work well -- it just returned a mostly empty swagger file.

Comment: Maybe you have some errors in your swagger file. Try http://editor.swagger.io, it helped me more than once to fix issues in my swagger files.